# ruby aws-s3 bucket problem

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm trying to test the aws-s3 gem for ruby, but I'm getting a weird reply:

I connect, and can see I am connected, then I run: AWS::S3::Service.buckets and get the [] reply as expected, then I create a bucket AWS::S3::Bucket.create('some-name') and get true as a reply, then I run AWS::S3::Service.buckets but still get the empty array as an answer?

Comment: it just took a real long time for aws-s3 to create and deploy the buckets. But when I access the s3 bucketname.s3.amazon.com I get an access denied

Comment: what is the default ACL settings while creating a bucket using aws-s3 gem? Try to get the signed URL of the bucket, then you'll be able to access it using the same. BTW, have you tries right_aws gem. It is very intuitive and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

A quick follow up, since I've had this same issue. Apparently when you first create a bucket, it won't show up in your list of buckets if you run `Service.buckets` right away. However, you can immediately use the bucket to upload and download items.

It's a bit odd, since right at this moment, the `Service.buckets` test returns an empty list for me, but I can use the bucket I just created without trouble. (Of course, this requires that I know the exact name of the bucket I want to work with myself.)

In any case, as your comment says, I'm assuming this is a timing issue on Amazon's side (rather than a problem with the gem). *Follow-up*: an hour later and the bucket shows up for `Service.buckets`. So, to summarize: you can create a bucket and work on it right away (i.e. add items, download items), but the example code on the [gem's homepage](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) is a bit misleading. Immediate attempts to look up new buckets by name don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
**AWS::S3::Bucket.find('some-name')**

Comment: Add some extra documentation.